# "Failed to cache field with id" unexpected error on list item edit

Tags: 2010, list, lookup-column, error

Some of our users are receiving "Unexpected errors" when modifying list items. They are third party, but have access to our internal SharePoint site. Our site admin sees "Failed to cache field with id" errors when checking logs.

I am not able to recreate error when doing same change on the list items. This problem is reoccurring for ~5 third party users.

How can I troubleshoot this?

A MS employee mentioned content database size/transaction log space... would this transaction log space change based on end-user saving changes?
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/72cfe4c1-ff23-455a-b562-8cfcc2ee45db/sp-log-failed-to-cache-field-with-id?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

> Failed to cache field with id "{...}", overwrite=0
>
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.LookupField.Validate()     at System.Web.UI.Page.Validate()     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)     at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Thank you for your time,

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any Custom Webpart on the page? Are you getting the error on the page load or while saving? if you are having custom webpart please check the permissions of the users

Comment: It's while saving. There is a Custom Webpart (JS files for front-end validation etc.). The Webpart does not have audience targetting, our users have required read permissions to the JS files too.